# Expo Action Sheet gives type error, can't assign return type Promise<void> to type of void | Promise<void>

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

Here is the code I am using to show an action sheet base of the expo documentation:
https://github.com/expo/react-native-action-sheet

The takePicture and pickImage functions both have type signatures:
`() => Promise<null | undefined>`

```
const options = ["Take Photo", "Upload From Library", "Cancel"]
const cancelButtonIndex = 2

showActionSheetWithOptions(
  { options, cancelButtonIndex },
  async (selectedIndex: number) => {
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        console.log("taking photo")
        await takePicture()

        break
      case 1:
        console.log("uploading from gallery")
        await pickImage()
        break

      case cancelButtonIndex:
      // Canceled
    }
  }
)
```

I believe my code matches the docs, but I get the following type error:

```
Argument of type '(selectedIndex: number) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(i?: number | undefined) => void | Promise<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'selectedIndex' and 'i' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

I tried introducing dummy Promises to make the selector function match the correct type signature, but I get a different type error, `The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<void>'?ts(1064)`

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know what. Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the type hint on selectedIndex in the callback function fixes the error. The correct type is `number | undefined`.